Fix MPV window in one axis in X11
I'm making a touchscreen rear view mirror using a Pi4b, and an 11.9" monitor at 1480x320px.
I'm playing two rtsp feeds in MPV. They are both 1920x1080, rotated 90deg.
I'm using --geometry to display the two feeds side by side.
One is opening at 1080 wide x 1920 high, the other at 400w. I can use the touchscreen to move the mpv window around the screen to adjust what area of the stream I'm viewing.
However, I only want to be able to move the window in Y - not X. So I can scroll up and down the stream, but not move it side to side on the display.
Is this achievable? Either limiting the touch input to vertical movements or preventing the window moving in X would be ideal

temporary fix achieved using xdotool in a bash loop to set x position; if someone can come up with a smoother method then please do comment
